# How to install Epson xp-750?

Tags: printing, epson

I am a first time user of Ubuntu, and struggle to install a printer,
my printer is **Epson xp-750**

A link to how this is done is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[from this link](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=TR&CN2=&DSCMI=19821&DSCCHK=7a34e462a7950c76687c970a57fd822fafe4c788)

just download the suitable driver which extension is .deb for your system(64 or 32 bit). And click the .deb file to install it.